# How to configure Raspberry Pi 3 as a Jump Server?

Tags: ssh, terminal, file-sharing, tftp, openssh

Using a Linux/Windows PC, I want to download a file from a Windows server. However, I want to use a Raspberry Pi in between to act as a Jump Server.

**Linux/Windows (client)------> Pi (jump server)---------->Windows Server**

Therefore, I want to do:

```
tftp -g -t i -f $PATH_FILE $RASPBERRY_PI_IP
```

How do I need to configure the Pi so when I do that, I get the file from the server?

I found this command and run it in the Linux client:

```
ssh -L 69:WINDOWS_SERVER_IP:69 pi@RASPBERRY_PI_IP
```

However, what this does it's to log me in the Pi from the Linux client and what I want to do is just to send the command to download the file.

**Update**: I did the exact configuration **@Ingo** suggested in his answer but, from the Pi, if I do `put /home/pi/test.py`, I'm getting *Transfer timed out.* Also, I enabled the TFTP client in the mswin-client and if I do `tftp Pi_address put C:\Users\Downloads\adapter.png`, I get *Connect request failed*. One thing I noticed is that I can ping the Pi from the mswin-client but not the mswin-client from the Pi...and I can pint Pi<->mswin-server on both directions. What could it be wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is tftp the only program you want to use?

Comment: @Ingo yes, maybe I need to use sftp instead temporary because tftp is not available at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With specific services like **tftp** you can use port forwarding on the Raspberry Pi to forward the network traffic to the MS Windows computer. For my example I will use interface **eth0**. Just change it if you use another interface, e.g. **wlan0**. Then ensure from the RasPi that you can ping all involved devices. I will use these names:

```
rpi ~$ ping client
rpi ~$ ping raspberrypi
rpi ~$ ping mswin-server
```

You can map these names to ip addresses in `/etc/hosts`.

**tftp** uses port 69 by default. If you want to use other ports you should find the places in the example where to change it. To enable port forwarding we use **iptables** but first we have to enable ip forwarding, so we have to do:

```
rpi ~$ echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
rpi ~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 --dport 69 -j DNAT --to-destination mswin-server:69
rpi ~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d mswin-server --dport 69 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

With **tftp-hpa** for example you should now be able to get files on `client` from `mswin-server`, if using the default port 69, with:

```
client ~$ tftp raspberrypi -c get hello.txt
```

To make all this persistent first uncomment `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Then use this unit file to create a new service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit port-forwarding.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them, and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Port forwarding
BindsTo=systemd-networkd.service
After=systemd-networkd.service
# If you use dhcpcd instead of systemd-networkd change to
#BindsTo=dhcpcd.service
#After=dhcpcd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 --dport 69 -j DNAT --to-destination mswin-server:69
ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d mswin-server --dport 69 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

ExecStopPost=-/usr/sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -p udp -d mswin-server --dport 69 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ExecStopPost=-/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 --dport 69 -j DNAT --to-destination mswin-server:69

[Install]
WantedBy=systemd-networkd.service
# If you use dhcpcd instead of systemd-networkd change to
#WantedBy=dhcpcd.service
```

Reboot.

Comment: thanks a lot! however, after following all the steps, I do "client ~$ tftp mswin-server_USER@raspberrypi_IP -c get hello.txt" and it doesn't work. it tries to connect to the raspberry (I know because of the correct password I to input). Am I missing something?

Comment: @itd Is file `hello.txt` available on mswin-server? Can you get it on the RasPi with tftp from mswin-server? What tftp program are you using on Linux?

Comment: Actually, I'm using sftp, so I did everything that you said but set port 22 instead of 69 and wrote "sftp" insted of "tftp"...but it should behave the same, right?

Comment: @itd No, **sftp** does not use the **t**rivial-ftp protocol. sftp uses the default ftp protocol in addition with an encrypted **s**ecure component: two reasons why it does not work (wrong protocol and encrypted). Please install and use `tftp-hpa`. Are you sure that on the mswin-server is a trivial-ftp server running?

Comment: I have a Filezilla server running on mswin-server. Let me know if I can try a different one, please. Also, if you know a client for Windows, my testing should be much more easier :)

Comment: @itd I'm completely unfamiliar with Microsoft Windows here on Raspberry Pi, so I cannot help. **ftp** (also sftp) and **tftp** are different. For usual file transfer normally ftp is used with password authentication. For simple and quick download of system files (netboot) without any security tftp is used. Of course you can use tftp for file download with lack of authentication and encryption. First you have to decide what you want to use, and then examine what your server is supporting.

Comment: I installed a TFTP server in the mswin-server and I did the exact configuration you suggested but, from the Pi, if I do "put /home/pi/test.py", I'm getting "Transfer timed out." Also, I enabled the TFTP client in the mswin-client and if I do "tftp Pi_address put C:\Users\Downloads\adapter.png", I get "Connect request failed". One thing I noticed is that I can ping the Pi from the mswin-client but not the mswin-client from the Pi...and I can pint Pi<->mswin-server on both directions. What could it be wrong?

Comment: @itd Please add the information from the comment to your question.

Comment: @itd seems your MS Windows devices does not work as expected. First try to use tftp direct from *client* to *mswin-server*.

Comment: my mswin-server wasn't working properly. I was using TFTPD32 but I think it's not possible to use access it from the terminal. The client is a Kali Linux machine. let me try to find a different tftp server and check again :)